# Axios how to get data inside of square brackets?

Tags: javascript, axios, discord

So I'm new with **Axios** and I'm trying to make a Discord bot that takes info from an api website and uses it. The issue is the data given looks like:

`{"status":1,"size":1,"result":[{"number":"9999",`  and so on.

How do I get the data inside of the [ ]? I tried:

```
var teamNumber = response.data.result.number
```

but it doesn't work.
I can get response.data.status, but not result.number
TLDR: how to get 9999 from `{"result":[{"number":"9999",` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result is an array; if you want to get the first element from it (and get that element's "number" field) you'd do:

```
console.log(response.data.result[0].number);
```

If you want to loop over them you'd do:

```
response.data.result.map(el => {
    console.log(el.number);
});
```

Comment: `map` shouldn't be used for looping over an array, unless the intention is to mutate each array value. You should use `forEach` for simply iterating the data.

Comment: Thanks. I realized it was an array, but I guess I just wasn't thinking :P